# Detect if iOS is using webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, browser-feature-detection

I was wondering if it's possible to detect if an iOS user is using the webapp, or just visiting the normal way with safari browser.

The reason I want to achieve is that on a iOS webapp when a user click on a link, he will get redirected to the Safari browser. So I'm using the following workaround to make him stay in the webapp(prevent the switching to safari browser).

```
$( document ).on("click",".nav ul li a",
        function( event ){

        // Stop the default behavior of the browser, which
        // is to change the URL of the page.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Manually change the location of the page to stay in
        // "Standalone" mode and change the URL at the same time.
        location.href = $( event.target ).attr( "href" );

        }
    );
```

But I want this workaround only to happen when the user is using the webapp, I want it to be conditional for webapp users. So not on the default safari browser.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to detect this by using some javascript:

```
<script>
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) &&       // Check if "standalone" property exists
    window.navigator.standalone){               // Test if using standalone navigator

    // Web page is loaded via app mode (full-screen mode)
    // (window.navigator.standalone is TRUE if user accesses website via App Mode)

} else {

    // Web page is loaded via standard Safari mode
    // (window.navigator.standalone is FALSE if user accesses website in standard safari)
}
</script>
</head>
```

Now the extra check `"standalone" in window.navigator` is needed because some browsers do not have the `standalone` property and you don't want your code to crash for those browsers.

Comment: Nice and simple answer! I searched stackoverflow ofc but for some reason that topic didn't pop up. Not even when I entered the title of the my question... Thanks!

Comment: And I will, just need to wait 3 more minutes ;)

Comment: @koningdavid: Glad to help you out!

Comment: in typescript use window.navigator['standalone']

Answer (score 15):

iOS and Chrome WebApp behaves different, thats the reason i came to following:

```
isInWebAppiOS = (window.navigator.standalone == true);
isInWebAppChrome = (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
```

Comment: Be careful with `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches`: it is also `true` in desktop Chrome popup windows.