# Know if website launched from home screen shortcut

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios7

I'm relatively new to web development and I was requested to add a popup message suggeting the user to add the website shortcut to his/her mobile home screen.

I already have the popup running but my boss is asking me to detect if the user launched the website from the shorcut to not show again the popup and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i)) {  
            $.fancybox({
               'width': '50%', //Use percentage to maintain responsiveness
               'height': '50%',
               'autoScale': true,
               'autoDimensions': false,
               'transitionIn': 'fade',
               'transitionOut': 'fade',
               'centerOnScroll': true,
               'type': 'inline',
               'href': '#mob_popup',
               padding: 8,
               helpers: {
                   overlay: {
                       css: {
                           'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45)'
                       }
                   }
               }


           });
```

Comment: Cannot your shortcut contains some URL parameter to distinct it?

Comment: show how you implemented the popup

Comment: you provide some extra parameters in url for mobile

Comment: There are existing plugins that will handle the popup and detection for you. I suggest not re-inventing the wheel, here.

Comment: For the popup I used this Fancybox thing:

Comment: Jain could you please provide more info on your suggetion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript to check the `window.navigator.standalone` property. If you're launched from the home screen, that property should come up `true` and if you're in Safari (or another browser) it will be `false`.

Comment: In my understanding this could work but only for iOS problem at this point would be Android.

Answer (score 2):

- For iOS devices, use `window.navigator.standalone === true`
- For Android devices, use `window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches`

See [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932368/14804363) for reference.