# PWA running fullscreen in Chrome Android does not honor Display-mode: standalone

Tags: android, google-chrome, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

Neither one of the methods used to detect `standalone` mode in Chrome Android [work in my PWA](https://licitaciones.chilediseno.org)

This is the CSS method I tried

```
@media all and (display-mode: standalone) {
    /* Here goes the CSS rules that will only apply if app is running standalone */
}
```

And this is the Javascript method (line 171-175, 297-306)

```
function isRunningStandalone() {
    return (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
}
...
if (isRunningStandalone()) {
    /* This code will be executed if app is running standalone */
}
```

Neither one of them worked: Testing `isRunningStandalone()` remotely in Chrome Android returns `false`, even though the example works.

(example made by @josemmo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516083/345605))

I have tested the code in iOS and 3 different Android Phones. iOS works perfectly.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=850465 Can you reference the sample in the bug report as it appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem: `manifest.json` has to have `"display": "standalone"`

`"display": "fullscreen"` will not work. I could not test for it either.