# is there a way to determine if the user is visiting my website via iphone bookmark (add to home screen) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a dialog in my website's home page that opens if the iphone users are visiting my website for the first time and inside the dialog i'm suggesting users to add my website to their home screen for a quicker access.

i also set a variable to true in cookies that expires within a week for not opening the dialog for the next week if the user visits again.

my problem is that i don't want to show the dialog at all when the user is visiting via the bookmark.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if web app running standalone on Chrome mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125337/how-to-detect-if-web-app-running-standalone-on-chrome-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

No. I do not think there is a way which can tell you if you were visited by a bookmark or via a browser on the iPhone. You can find out whether the user was an iPhone or Android user, or any OS for that matter.

Once a user clicks a link on their phone, the phone takes them to a browser or opens a "WebView" depending on the link. Even the WebViews might report only the phone type and basic info. when you query for it.

So, basically, No!

Comment: A solution would be to just add a link on your webpage which allows them to do this bookmark add, instead of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one GET when generate url of the marker,

like ?m=1,

to check it from 
js with window.location.search