# How to add functions (e.g. Reload) to a PWA Standalone App Status Bar?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, statusbar

How to add functions to a PWA Standalone App Status Bar. Like seen here in this app in a Standalone mode (attached image or link https://www.urzagatherer.app/ ) - Reload & Back.
Thanks
Olli

Comment: Please see here - https://www.urzagatherer.app/

Comment: Is there an image attached to this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, this question can be closed as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516083/385997