# Restricting Access to a Specific Page in Website to PWA Only

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a web project and have a specific requirement: I want to restrict access to a certain page on my website so that it can **only be accessed through the Progressive Web App** (PWA) and **not through a regular browser.**

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to detect if requests were sent from a specific `display-mode`, but you could probably configure the service worker to send a "secret" header with the request when the client's `display-mode` is standalone. On the server side you could reject requests without that header. It's not foolproof, of course.

Comment: anything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125337/how-to-detect-if-web-app-running-standalone-on-chrome-mobile) help?

Comment: Remove the ability to connect to this site using your domain
Or only show for a specific IP address

Comment: _"only be accessed through the Progressive Web App (PWA) and not through a regular browser."_ - PWAs are so-called **because** they're accessed through a "regular browser" - otherwise they wouldn't be _web_-apps...

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer I found

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
    console.log('Web app is running in standalone mode');
} else {
    console.log('Web app is not running in standalone mode');
    window.location.href = 'home page';
}
```